# How to use waitformultipleobject in C++

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, waitformultipleobjects

I am trying to write a code that will wait for client connections. As soon as it gets connected to a client, it should start reading a file and send it.

I need to have notifications for the socket handles, that is if connection gets lost from client side it will notify me so that I can try to reconnect.

Comment: From your problem description, it doesn't sound like WFMO (or WFSO) is what you should be looking at.

Answer (score 1):

If a connection is lost, it is up to the *client side* to reconnect. Servers do not connect or reconnect to clients.

If your server is simply dispensing a file, all you need to do is to accept connections and pass them to a handler that will invoke [TransmitFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740565%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) at some point and clean up.

Comment: The exception to the 'servers do not connect to clients' rule is a FTP data connection opened in "active" mode, but that is part of a defined protocol for data transfer, not a recovery mechanism of any kind.

Comment: Another example would be secure servers in the dial-up era that used call-back lists to establish connections.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the parts about waiting for client connections and sending a file are just for clarification and you already got that working. If not, there are lots of tutorials on [sockets](http://www.c-worker.ch/tuts/wstut_op.php#winsockstarten) and [file I/O](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) out there.

In your case, detecting whether or not a client is still connected should be simple. Since your server is sending a file as soon as the connection is made, the client will start reading from the socket as soon as it is open. The `read`-function blocks, as long as the connection is open and no data was received. If the connection is closed, it will return having read 0 bytes. At that point you know, that the connection was terminated and you can try to reconnect.

If you are not permanently reading from the socket but keeping it open for future communication, you should look into the [`select`-function](http://www.c-worker.ch/tuts/select.php#select), which allows monitoring one or more sockets and notifies you, as soon as one of them has an update (for example new data available or connection closed)

Comment: arayq2 has a point: servers don't generally manage reconnect logic.  If a connection is broken, the server should do nothing other than clean up.  Reconnecting should be up to the client.

Comment: @CareyGregory I thought he meant detect a disconnect on the client side. Although now that I read it again, I might have been wrong. Of course it is wrong for a server to manage reconnects. Not to mention impossible, in most cases.